# Trigger CSS animation with checkbox inside a fieldset

Tags: html, css, animation, checkbox, checked

I try to trigger an animation only when a checkbox is checked.
I have the following code :

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" >
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <input type="checkbox" class="mediaCheckbox" id="playCheck"/>
        <label data-role="button" class="fa fa-play" id="play" for="playCheck"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="mediaCheckbox" id="muteCheck"/>
        <label data-role="button" class="fa fa-bell" id="mute" for="muteCheck"></label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="stuffToAnimate"></div>
```

and the following CSS :

```
#stuffToAnimate {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: ball 11s ease-in-out 0s infinite normal; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
#playCheck:checked **XXX**{
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ball {
    0%   {top:5%;}
    40%  {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    50%  {-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);top:80%;}
    90%  {-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);top:5%;}
}
```

My problem is: How to complete the `**XXX**` selector in order to trigger the animation. I could put the checkbox `#playCheck` in the same level as `#stuffToAnimate`, but it would mess up my presentation.

Comment: Since there is no parent selector, you can't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use jquery to give `#stuffToAnimate` a class

```
$('#playCheck:checkbox').click(function() {

    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        $("#stuffToAnimate").addClass("animate");
    }
    else {
        $("#stuffToAnimate").removeClass("animate");
    }
});
```

your css will look like this

```
.animate{
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}
```